# Run Web automation tests on Jenkins Build Server

Tags: azure, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have the following setup:
Windows Server 2016 VM in Azure with Jenkins and .NET.
The nighlty job fetches the repo and runs the automated E2E tests using Specflow and xUnit. The web-related steps run silently (i.e. without displaying the browser window). How can I configure the job to display the browser during test run?

P.S. When I run the same suite using xunit console runner the window gets displayed.

Comment: What browser is being used by Selenium for the headless tests running in Jenkins?  Typically if you aren't using a service like SauceLabs, you'll need to capture the output in the tests themselves.  This isn't in the Specflow or xUnit pieces themselves, it is in the test implementations.

Moreover, Jenkins is intended to be automated and unattended - so "displaying while the test is running" should more likely be "capturing to review".  Automated tests are generally not "monitored" by people, while console tests are.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. You're correct, I'm not using any third-party 
services. I use Chrome web browser for the headless tests.
Can you provide me with some example of capturing the output during the test run? @SteveHarris

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that whenever a test fails it's not sufficient to review the console output; sometimes a screen shot is crucial for understanding what really happened there.

Comment: Sadly the specifics of capturing output depends on the web driver and language you are using in the tests.  However, all of them have the capability of capturing screen shots.  I typically incorporate screen shot capture into the tests at places where I want to confirm visually a layout (or pass same to an analyzer), or whenever an exception occurs.  This almost always has to be done in the test code.